# Providing the option of choosing any special products after doing add to cart in magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to give new feature to my site,that when user selects any product and do "add to cart" ,after this he should get a window of special products which he wants to purchase with that product and if he dont want then he will not choose any product and do "proceed to checkout"
like in www.fnp.com.

Can I impliment this fuctionality in magento

If yes please provide me some links.I will be thankful to you.

Comment: Why not use cross sell feature of magento?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the crosssell function of Magento. If you want the crosssell box to be displayed as a popup (overlay) in the cart just use `jQuery UI` (you must add `Query UI` to Magento) to make it a modal box by adding this at the bottom of your cart page:

```
jQuery('.crosssell').dialog();
```

You can even give parameters to the dialog

```
jQuery('.crosssell').dialog({width:500, height:300});
```

You can achieve this even without `jQuery`, by using `Window` from prototype, but I'm not really good with that so I cannot give you sample code. [But here are some simple demos](http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/samples.html)

Comment: Can u pls tell me in which file I have to add this jQuery('.crosssell').dialog();

Comment: `app\design\frontend\{interface}\{theme}\template\checkout\cart\crosssell.phtml`